# Go to other fragment from a fragment

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

I'm really sorry for this stupid question but I've been reading various things but seems can't get through my thick skull. I'm really desperate here so please bear with me.

So I got one fragment full of text, say `fragment_chapter_1.xml`. One of the text need further explanation so I want to make it when the text (`Copyright Act (Amendment) 1997`) got clicked (it is not set clickable in xml layout), it will go to `fragment_explain_law.xml`.

The `fragment_explain_law.xml` have a TextView `explainLaw`, which will get setText (in `ExplainLawFragment.java`) to it's own explanation of the text clicked in `fragment_chapter_1.xml`. I use this way because if other text got clicked, it will reuse the same `fragment_explain_law.xml` but the `explainLaw` will set to different explanation.

Here's the code.

1. In `Chapter1Fragment.java`, it will view `fragment_chapter_one.xml`. `law1` is id for `Copyright Act (Amendment) 1997`.

   ```
   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chapter_1, container, false);

   law1 = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.law1);
   law1.setOnClickListener(this);

   // Inflate the layout for this fragment
   return rootView;
   }
   ```
2. When `law1` got clicked, `fragment_explain_law.xml` will be shown. For that, I make it by go to `ExplainLawFragment.java` (am I doing it right?).

   ```
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
   // when law1 till law11 clicked, go to ExplainLawFragment.java to view fragment_explain_law.xml
   Fragment fragment = null;
   String title = null;

   switch (v.getId()) {
       case R.id.law1:
           // view explainLaw
           fragment = new ExplainLawFragment();
           title = "Copyright Act (Amendment) 1997";
           break;
   }
   ```

   }
3. In `ExplainLawFragment.java`

   ```
   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_explain_law, container, false);
   explainLaw = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.explainLaw);
   explainLaw.setText("blahblahblah");
   // Inflate the layout for this fragment
   return rootView;
   }
   ```

Result: Nothing happen.

Logcat when I click `law1`: `V/SettingsInterface:  from settings cache , name = sound_effects_enabled , value = 1`

Where did I go wrong? Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call second fragment like this....

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
// when law1 till law11 clicked, go to ExplainLawFragment.java to view fragment_explain_law.xml
Fragment fragment = null;
String title = null;

switch (v.getId()) {
case R.id.law1:
    // view explainLaw
    fragment = new ExplainLawFragment();
    title = "Copyright Act (Amendment) 1997";
 FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
    break;
```

}

Hope this will help you..

Comment: though the title not changed

Comment: you can set title in second fragment onCreateView() method like.... getActivity().setTitle("Your title");